# How does generative language model work in the natural language processing?

Tags: nlp, nltk, probability, probability-theory

AFAIK, the generative language model is nothing but **a probability distribution for some vocabulary**. I am wondering how to use this probability distribution to generate a stream of words, i.e. language?

If I always pick the word with biggest probability, it will always be the same word because the distribution is fixed.

I am not sure if I understand it correctly. Could anyone provide a concrete operational example?

Comment: FWIW, it sounds like your question is about generating words from a unigram language model. Higher order language models would include some notion of history (e.g., previous words and/or syntactic context). In general, higher order language models will generate more coherent streams of words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't pick the word with highest probability. You pick a random word, but no uniformly - with the probability in the model.

So, if you have 2 words in a model: "yes" and "no", and the probability distribution is 2/3 "yes", 1/3 "no", than the generated text may look like this:

```
yes no no yes yes no yes yes yes no yes yes yes
```

I.e., you'll have approximately 2/3 "yes" in the text and 1/3 "no".

EDIT

Here's a simple way to sample from the distribution:

1. Generate a random number from 0 to 1.
2. Iterate over all words in the model, summing their probability weights. As soon as the sum is larger than the generated number, emit the current word.

Here's an example:

Suppose you've generated `0.8`. You start from `yes` and the accumulated probability weight will be `0.67`, so you take next word `no` and get the accumulated weight `1.0` which is greater than `0.8`, so you emit `no`.

Suppose next time you have `0.5`, then you need to emit `yes`.

Comment: Thanks. But I know that the outcome stream should be like that in theory. But my question is how to generate it in practice?

Comment: I see, I've updated the answer with one variant of how to do that.

Comment: So following your example, suppose after I get the "yes" with 0.67, I get the "no" with 0.5. So neither of them is above 0.8, what should I do? Shall I continue iterating the model and keep summing the probability weight until it is above 0.8? After I emit one word, should I repeat the step 1 to get a new random number between 0 and 1? Or just keep using 0.8?

Comment: Yes, you generate a new random number for each sample. As for the first question: you've got it backwards. In this case you'll get `yes` is the generated number is below `0.67` and `no` otherwise. If you'll have 3 words: `yes`, `no`, `maybe` with equal probabilities, you'll need to take `yes` if the generated number is from `0` to `1/3`, `no` if it's from `1/3` to `2/3`, and `maybe` if it's above `2/3`. You can think of it as placing you words on a `[0,1]` section, each word taking the size proportional to the probability.